# How to import a existant model and make it a form (view) then translate it into a template

Tags: django

I have a `models.py` which contain all my database, I want to import it into a view called `forms.py` and then translate into my template in a nice form.

This is my idea of `forms.py`:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm 
from app.models import Article

# Create the form class.
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserInformation
```

I have no idea how to write the template. Could anyone help?

Comment: You should attempt to solve the problem yourself first. Try something, then post your attempt for us to help you with

Comment: The docs have a perfectly good [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#the-template)(s), What didn't work when you tried them?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're calling a form a view here. They're quite different things.

Comment: Okay let's say my models.py is in the folder app (app/models.py) and I want to import the model called 'class UserInformation(models.Model):..' into a form on my view forms.py. I have writted the following thing on my form.py : `code`                                                                                              from django.forms import ModelForm 
from app.models import Userinformation

# Create the form class.
class Userinformation(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserInformation `code`                                                                 Is this correct ?

Comment: Stop saying "my view forms.py". A form is not a view!

Comment: Ok sorry I can't edit it now :s

Comment: In any case, Sayse has already pointed you to the docs on this. If those aren't enough, you need to state *exactly* what your issue is.

Comment: They say to me " ImproperlyConfigured at /
Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form UserInformation needs updating. " When I write this on forms.py : ```from django.forms import ModelForm
from app.models import UserInformation

# Create the form class.
class UserInformation(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserInformation```

Comment: How can I create a view from my forms.py ?

Comment: OK, so a) why didn't you say that at the beginning, and b) why don't you do what the error message suggests?

Comment: AND STOP CALLING IT A VIEW!

Comment: I didn't call it a view, I just want to create view out of it  :x https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/ Is this how i should do it ? Thanks. I have fixed the error message, I am now trying to create a view of my forms.py which will redirect it to the template. This is how I should do it right ?